# How To Use insert array's data into different rows using For Loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, database

I am inserting data to the database using a for Loop,
I am having data stored in Array to insert into table (ex.- questionIdArray)
I am sharing my code below. Is this approach correct or should I refine this.

```
$retriveDataForJSON= mysql_query($querytoGetUsageOfSelectStudents);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retriveDataForJSON))
{
    $USER_ID= $row["USER_ID"];                          
    $SESSION_ID= $row["SESSION_ID"];
    $QUESTION_IDS = $row["QUESTION_IDS"];
    $questionIdArray=explode(',',$QUESTION_IDS);
    $RESPONSES= $row["RESPONSES"];
    $responseArray=explode('|',$RESPONSES);
    $RIGHT_OR_WRONG = $row["RIGHT_OR_WRONG"];
    $rightWrongArray=explode('|',$RIGHT_OR_WRONG);
    $TIME_PER_QUESTION = $row["TIME_PER_QUESTION"];
    $timePerQuestionArray=explode('|',$TIME_PER_QUESTION);
    $QUIZ_SIZE = $row["QUIZ_SIZE"];
    $CORRECT_ANSWERS = $row["CORRECT_ANSWERS"];
    $COURSE_ID= $row["COURSE_ID"];
    $TOPIC_NAME = $row["TOPIC_NAME"];
    $SUBTOPIC_IDS = $row["SUBTOPIC_IDS"];
    //$subtopicNameArray = getSubtopicNameArray(subtopicIds)
    //$topicNameArray = getTopicNameArray(subtopicIds)
    $START_TIME = $row["START_TIME"];
    $END_TIME = $row["END_TIME"];
    $TIME_TAKEN = $row["TIME_TAKEN"];   
 for($i=0;$i<sizeof($questionIdArray);$i++){

        //Insert Query To Temp Table
   $queryToInInsertInTable= "INSERT INTO `temp_assessment_data`(`Q_ID`, `RESPONCE`, `W/R/B`, `TIME_TAKEN`, `USER_ID`, `TOPIC`, `SUBTOPIC`, `CLASS`, `SCHOOL`, `BLOCK`, `DISTRICT`) VALUES
    ('$questionIdArray[$i]','$responseArray[$i]','$rightWrongArray[$i]','$timePerQuestionArray[$i]','$USER_ID','$className','$schoolName','$blockName','$District')";
}
```

Comment: please describe array with value. and full code.

Comment: Just Uploaded Full Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check define all variable with value

```
<?php
$retriveDataForJSON= mysql_query($querytoGetUsageOfSelectStudents);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retriveDataForJSON))
{
    $USER_ID= $row["USER_ID"];                          
    $SESSION_ID= $row["SESSION_ID"];
    $QUESTION_IDS = $row["QUESTION_IDS"];
    $questionIdArray=explode(',',$QUESTION_IDS);
    $RESPONSES= $row["RESPONSES"];
    $responseArray=explode('|',$RESPONSES);
    $RIGHT_OR_WRONG = $row["RIGHT_OR_WRONG"];
    $rightWrongArray=explode('|',$RIGHT_OR_WRONG);
    $TIME_PER_QUESTION = $row["TIME_PER_QUESTION"];
    $timePerQuestionArray=explode('|',$TIME_PER_QUESTION);
    $QUIZ_SIZE = $row["QUIZ_SIZE"];
    $CORRECT_ANSWERS = $row["CORRECT_ANSWERS"];
    $COURSE_ID= $row["COURSE_ID"];
    $TOPIC_NAME = $row["TOPIC_NAME"];
    $SUBTOPIC_IDS = $row["SUBTOPIC_IDS"];
    //$subtopicNameArray = getSubtopicNameArray(subtopicIds)
    //$topicNameArray = getTopicNameArray(subtopicIds)
    $START_TIME = $row["START_TIME"];
    $END_TIME = $row["END_TIME"];
    $TIME_TAKEN = $row["TIME_TAKEN"];   
     for($i=0;$i<sizeof($questionIdArray);$i++){

            //Insert Query To Temp Table
         $queryToInInsertInTable = "insert into `temp_assessment_data` set 
                            `Q_ID`      = '".$questionIdArray[$i]."',
                            `RESPONCE`  = '".$responseArray[$i]."',
                            `W/R/B`     = '".$rightWrongArray[$i]."',
                            `TIME_TAKEN`= '".$timePerQuestionArray[$i]."',
                            `USER_ID`   = '".$USER_ID."',
                            `TOPIC`     = '".$TOPIC_NAME."',
                            `SUBTOPIC`  = '".$SUBTOPIC_IDS."',
                            `CLASS`     = '".$className."',
                            `SCHOOL`    = '".$schoolName."',
                            `BLOCK`     = '".$blockName."',
                            `DISTRICT`  = '".$District."
                            ";

        mysql_query($queryToInInsertInTable) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks... It is working with this easy way...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.` char concatenation to insert array values, and to concat `$queryToInInsertInTable` with itselft :

```
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($questionIdArray); $i++){
    //Insert Query To Temp Table
    $queryToInInsertInTable .= "INSERT INTO `temp_assessment_data`(`Q_ID`, `RESPONCE`, `W/R/B`, `TIME_TAKEN`, `USER_ID`, `TOPIC`, `SUBTOPIC`, `CLASS`, `SCHOOL`, `BLOCK`, `DISTRICT`) VALUES 
    ('".$questionIdArray[$i]."','".$responseArray[$i]."','".$rightWrongArray[$i]."','".$timePerQuestionArray[$i]."','".$USER_ID."','".$className."','".$schoolName."','".$blockName."','".$District."')";
}
```

> Caution with SQL injection, check the array values, they must not come from the client side (GET or POST values), to prevent SQL injection. Use PDO mysql instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use the . for concatenation to insert array values.

```
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($questionArray); $i++){
//Insert Query To Temp Table
$queryToInsertInTable .= "INSERT INTO `temp_assessment_data`(`Q_ID`, `RESPONCE`, `W/R/B`, `TIME_TAKEN`, `USER_ID`, `TOPIC`, `SUBTOPIC`, `CLASS`, `SCHOOL`, `BLOCK`, `DISTRICT`) VALUES 
('".$questionIdArray[$i]."','".$responseArray[$i]."','".$rightWrongArray[$i]."','".$timePerQuestionArray[$i]."','".$USER_ID."','".$className."','".$schoolName."','".$blockName."','".$District."')";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     for($i=0;$i<sizeof($questionIdArray);$i++){

    //Insert Query To Temp Table
    $queryToInInsertInTable= "INSERT INTO `temp_assessment_data`(`Q_ID`, 
    `RESPONCE`, `W/R/B`, `TIME_TAKEN`, `USER_ID`, `TOPIC`, `SUBTOPIC`, 
     `CLASS`, `SCHOOL`, `BLOCK`, `DISTRICT`) VALUES



   (\"".$questionIdArray[$i]."\",\"".$responseArray[$i]."\",
   \"".$rightWrongArray[$i]."\",\"".$timePerQuestionArray[$i]."\",
    \"".$USER_ID."\",\"".$className."\",\"".$schoolName."\",
    \"".$blockName."\",\"".$District."\")"; }
```

that's because you should use \" instead of ', it may give you errors if you're using phpmyadmin

Comment: `phpmyadmin`? why would it gives errors? and phpmyadmin is not a database